# How do store a list of sorted tables with an SQL SHOW TABLES statement?

Tags: php, sql

I am using the following code to show all tables, but how do I store the tables into a sorted array:

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM ".$counter_database." ORDER BY TABLES DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$outArray = array();
while($table = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $outArrayx[] = $table;
}
```

The following code spits out the data:

```
foreach ($outArrayx as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $keys => $values) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$values." WHERE user_id='0'"; 
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if (strpos($values, "ckia") === 0) {
            while($table = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $outArray[] = $table;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worst practice looping non-prepared selects.

Comment: `ORDER BY` is not allowed in `SHOW TABLES`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller You can't use placeholders for table names, so what are you suggesting as an alternative?

Comment: Put the table names in a PHP array, and use PHP's `sort()` function to sort it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not look carefully. Yes, table names can not be parameterized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the table names in a PHP array, and then sort the array. And if you don't nest it in the row, you don't need nested loops when you process it.

You can't use `ORDER BY` with `SHOW TABLES`, but you *can* use `LIKE` to select only tables that fit a pattern. Then you don't need the `if` statement in your loop.

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM ".$counter_database." LIKE 'ckia%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$outArray = array();
while($table = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $outArrayx[] = $table[0];
}

sort ($outArrayx);

foreach ($outArrayx as $table) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE user_id='0'"; 
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $outArray[] = $row;
    }
}
```